# Проблемы с наследованием приватных переменных Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Пытаюсь выстроить грамотную архитектуру насколько позволяют навыки и опыт, но столкнулся с проблемой:

```
 AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute '_SeleniumBase__wait'
```

Структура кода следующая:

```
class SeleniumBase:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.__wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3, 0.3)
        ...

class Utils(SeleniumBase):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver
        ...

class Browser(Auth, Utils):
    def __init__(self, account_id: str, user_id: str):
        ...
        driver = Chrome(service=service, options=options)
        super().__init__(driver)
```

При вызове метода из SeleniumBase с использованием self.__wait получаю эту ошибку.
Вызываю из Utils, решил проверить схожую структуру и все работает нормально.

Comment: замените двойное подчеркивание одинарным для методов и свойств которые должны быть наследованы

Comment: Не помогло, вместо _SeleniumBase__wait, _wait и wait без подчеркиваний

Comment: а! у тебя проблема же с классом Browser. тогда поменяй порядок классов в наследовании: `class Browser(Utils, Auth):`

Comment: Действительно помогло, пожалуй больше почитаю про порядок наследования, спасибо!

Comment: help(Browser) покажет тебе порядок разрешения методов. И в ютубе можешь посмотреть видос "super это супер".